# if my handlers are in different file, my app gives 404 not found

Tags: routes, python-3.6, python-decorators, aiohttp

I was trying middlewares and was getting not found as coded by the middleware for the request even if the request was valid. Then I removed the middleware and tested if the request is working and it wasn't working. I am not sure what changed but AFAIR, these files were working.
If I add back the handlers from views.py namely index_view and subapp_view back to main.py, the code works.

This is main.py

```
from aiohttp import web
import asyncio

app_routes = web.RouteTableDef()
subapp_routes = web.RouteTableDef()


def init():
    greet = web.Application()
    greet.router.add_routes(subapp_routes)

    app.router.add_routes(app_routes)

    app.add_subapp('/greet/', greet)
    web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8089)


async def shutdown(server, handler, app):
    server.close()
    await server.wait_closed()
    app.client.close() # db connection closed
    await app.shutdown()
    await handler.finish_connections(10.0)
    await app.cleanup()


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
app = web.Application(loop=loop)

serv_generator, handler, application = loop.run_until_complete(init())
serv = loop.run_until_complete(serv_generator)

try:
    loop.run_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print(' Stop server begin')
finally:
    loop.run_until_complete(shutdown(serv, handler, application))
    loop.close()
print('Stop server end')
```

This is views.py

```
from aiohttp import web
from main import app_routes, subapp_routes

@app_routes.get('/')
async def index_view(request):
    return web.Response(text='index\n')


@subapp_routes.get('/{name}')
async def subapp_view(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    txt = "Hello {}\n".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)
```

Am I missing any import statement here? I am not getting any compiler error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it by hit and trial. Not sure why this is like this but apparently the decorator routes should be defined where they are used. So below is the corrected code!

main.py

```
from aiohttp import web
from views import app_routes, subapp_routes

    def init():
        greet = web.Application()
        greet.router.add_routes(subapp_routes)

        app.router.add_routes(app_routes)

        app.add_subapp('/greet/', greet)
        web.run_app(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=8089)


    async def shutdown(server, handler, app):
        server.close()
        await server.wait_closed()
        app.client.close() # db connection closed
        await app.shutdown()
        await handler.finish_connections(10.0)
        await app.cleanup()


    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    app = web.Application(loop=loop)

    serv_generator, handler, application = loop.run_until_complete(init())
    serv = loop.run_until_complete(serv_generator)

    try:
        loop.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print(' Stop server begin')
    finally:
        loop.run_until_complete(shutdown(serv, handler, application))
        loop.close()
    print('Stop server end')
```

views.py

```
from aiohttp import web

app_routes = web.RouteTableDef()
subapp_routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@app_routes.get('/')
async def index_view(request):
    return web.Response(text='index\n')


@subapp_routes.get('/{name}')
async def subapp_view(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name', "Anonymous")
    txt = "Hello {}\n".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting any errors, but the routes are not registered correctly.

I have not looked at the aiohttp code, but I assume that the decorator modifes the given route set. In Python this is evaluated when the source file is imported and parsed by the interpreter.

You need to make sure that the interpreter "sees" the `views.py` file through `import views`. In your example the file is ignored, because nothing is there to import it. You have to do that manually - it does not matter that you do not actually need the reference to it.